# Model predictions from cenGAM tobit1 family in R fall outside of left and right thresholds

Tags: r, gam

I am modeling proportional data. the response variable (y) is a proportion between, and including 0 and 1. Model predictions generated from cenGAM tobit1 family in R fall outside of left and right thresholds and result in negative numbers and those that exceed 1 even though I specify the respective thresholds at 0 and 1. I have run similar tobit models using vglm and the predicted output remains within the specified threshold. I have tried using na.omit on my data as well to no avail. Any help on keeping predictions censored between, and including 0 and 1 would be most helpful. Thanks, and see code below.

```
library(mgcv)
library(cenGAM)

df <- data.frame("y"=c( NA, NA, NA,  NA,  NA,  NA,  NA, NA, 0.68888889, 0.51923077,
                      0.37829457, 0.25364431, 0.23420074, 0.15662651, 0.19101124,
                      0.06250000, 0.06451613, 0.00000000, 0.00000000, 0.00000000,
                      NA,NA),
                 "x"=c( NA, 65.53143, 65.89143, 65.66000, 64.65714, 65.22286, 64.91429,
                        63.44857, 64.24571, 60.36286, 60.85143, 59.33429,57.61143, 57.74000,
                        57.17429, 54.70571, 51.72286, 49.97429, 48.79143, 47.35143, 45.96286, 45.83429))
```

```
cen_gammod1 <- gam(y ~ s(x,bs="cr"),family= tobit1(left.threshold=0,right.threshold=1), data =df,na=na.exclude)
```

Comment: can we have a [mcve] please?  Are you sure you are generating predictions on the response scale and not on some transformed/link scale?

Comment: yes, apologies. It defaults to an "identity" link I believe. I have tried changing the link to "log" which provides predictions in the realm, however, the point of the tobit specification for me is to model it normally with a simple restriction on the min and max of y. log link will most definitely provide smaller numbers slightly greater than 0, however, I want to truly model those 0's. A simple tobit regression model in vglm does such. I was hoping the GAM would capture the slightly less linear nature and address the slight heteroscedasticity present.

Comment: I know very little about how the package works. Maybe it generates "uncensored" predictions which could then be re-censored via `pmin(upper_bound, pmax(lower_bound, pred))` ?

Comment: This usage doesn't make sense for the model implied by the family. Your data aren't censored at 0 and 1 (censoring means in your case that you know some values are -infinity < x_i < 0 but not what the actual value is), they simply don't exist and as such the model is assuming something very different about the data. A more natural model for data on the unit interval would be the one implemented in the `betar()` family in *mgcv*, although it can't be used for exact 0 and 1 so it will apply an adjustment to move those values slightly away from the 0,1 boundary.

Comment: Thank you Gavin. Yes, that dawned on me later - I used a zero or one inflated beta reg model and it did the trick. Will compare with betar in mgcv.      Still though, why would it also not restrict the predicted response to fall within the 0,1 set? Other packages allow for this.